# mv file order file mv

Tags: shell, mv

How to choose in which order `mv` treat files? (I mean, I can invoke it manually, but the work of preserving paths and work recursively can become rapidly a problem)

I have an fs mounted on /mnt and another one mounted in /home

/mnt have all kind of files, in a lot of folders

I want to move all to /home

But I want to choose in what order moving them

Like for example I would like /mnt/a/t/d/v/file to be treated before /mnt/b/d/g/e/file

If there is any sorting available, I can work with it (I think)

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. `mv` treats files in the order that they're presented on the command line. `mv` doesn't preserve paths, with the exception that partial paths can be kept when moving directories, and it is not recursive. Please give an example of what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried.

Comment: I don't even slightly understand what you're asking. Perhaps you could [illustrate your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/726192/edit) with an example?

Comment: I saw a similar question in the past week (cannot find it now). I think what @aaa intends is "How can I merge one directory tree into another in the same file system, preserving the tree structure, creating new directories where needed, reconciling file name clashes and duplicate files, and using `mv` to avoid copying data."

Comment: There might be some issues you have not considered. (1) mv does not recurse, and it does not create directories. So you might need to run `mkdir -p /home/b/d/g/e` and many similar before moving anything. (2) What do you do if any file names are already present in /home, and (worse) if they have the same name but different contents? Personally I would tar create in /mnt, and pipe to tar extract in /home, because that would preserve permissions and dates, and create directories. Why do you care about the order this happens in ?

Comment: If files are already there, simply do nothing. Why would I need to recreate the whole structure by myself. Until today, since years of using Linux I did not did that. Tar seems convenient but files are constantly changing. I'd like to delete them as I move them. About permissions and date it's okay, it's really the content that matters here. I care about the order because some files are really more tedious to copy for some reason, so I would like to order them last

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show examples of what files exist and what result you want to get. Are there files that should not be moved? Does "If files are already there, simply do nothing" mean that you only want to move files that do not exist on the destination and keep others on the source? What do you mean with "some files are really more tedious to copy for some reason"? Faulty media? How do you imagine to specify which files need to be moved first? Why "delete them as I move them"? Adding background information to the question might help us to understand your problem.

Comment: Any files that is in path given should be moved, at least if it does not overwrite, else then do nothing or prompt for what to do / Yeah it means that / Yeah kind of faulty media/filesystem, giving an order really ease the thing / I personally imagine by giving a random order and bruteforce till it last only the "faulty medias" / Delete them as I move them, because it's a living filesystem who work with existing file and modifies it. I want to be clear about what theres is left in route

Comment: Please don't use comments to add clarification or requested information. Add all information to the question by [edit]ing it. Instead of adding requirements in a comment to the answer you should make everything clear in the question and mention in a comment that you have updated the question. If you have a faulty media you should unmount it, stop using the filesystem and create a copy using tools like [`ddrescue`](https://askubuntu.com/a/211579/1186757) to copy an image of the filesystem a new/error-free media and then mount the copy and copy the files to the final destination.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
mv /mnt/* /home/
```

It's the shell that expands `/mnt/*` to the list of matching files (for that pattern, that would be all the non-hidden files in `/mnt`) and passes the result to `mv`, so `mv` will receive `mv`, `/mnt/a`, `/mnt/b`, `/mnt/c`... `/home/` as separate arguments.

Shells sort their glob expansions lexically by default. In the zsh shell the order can be changed with the `o`/`O` glob qualifiers.

`/mnt/a` will be moved before `/mnt/b` because `a` sorts before `b` lexically. If you wanted to move them in reverse order, you'd do:

```
mv /mnt/*(DOn) /home/
```

in zsh (also adding the `D` qualifier to move hidden files as well).

If you wanted `/mnt/b` to be moved before anything else, you could do:

```
set -o extendedglob
mv /mnt/b /mnt/^b(D) /home/
```

Or:

```
mv /mnt/b /home/ && mv /mnt/*(D) /home/
```

Normally, `mv` just does some `rename()ing`, so it doesn't work recursively. However, when moving across file systems, it can't do that so it resorts to doing a recursive copy followed by removal of the original.

In `mv /mnt/* /home/`, where `/mnt` and `/home` are on two different filesystems, `/mnt/a` will be moved before `/mnt/b`, but when it comes to files within `/mnt/a` or `/mnt/b`, the order is unspecified and you generally can't control it.

To have a say on the order for those, you'd have to move individual files manually, or you could resorts to `cpio -p` or `pax -rw` which can be told to copy files in a given order (and remove the source by hand afterwards).

Comment: I like on what it resort, thats what I want. The order is only specified by shell here, because of the `*`. But for me it's even worse, because I just copy a folder, not using a wildcard, so the uncertainty is even from the first depth level. The given order should be gave file by file? I can pipe something that will generate this list. Does it preserve paths?